# java decompiler for eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, decompiler

I use JD for eclipse to decompile classes. There is a problem with line numbers. For example debugger shows current line 1123 but source code generated by JD has less than 1000 lines, however it shows correct (or very close to) lines in the comments

```
/*  519 */     this(new SunHTTPHandler());
```

while real line number is only 51.

Is it possible to solbe this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think JD has any ability to get the line numbers right. This is incredibly annoying, i know!

[Jad](http://www.varaneckas.com/jad) does a better job than JD with the line numbers. However, it does a worse job at decompilation. You could give it a try and see if it's good enough for you.

Alternatively, it should be a simple matter of [sed](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) scripting to massage the output files to get the line numbers right.

Comment: In 2015, it seems that JD is able to get line numbers right, FWIW.

Answer (score 1):

The [jadclipse plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jadclipse/) can sort the output of `jad` to align line numbers but the code is pretty limited (read: it often fails).